Curvature is determined completely by the metric in Tu's Differential geometry book
I was reading the book named "Differential Geometry: Connections, Curvature, and Charateristic Classes" by Loring W.Tu and stuck in the proof of Therema Egregium (in $\mathbb{R}^3$).
The line that I couldn't understand was: "Since $R_p(e_1,e_2)$ is deteremined completely by the metric,".
The definition of $R(X,Y)$ in the book is, given an affine connection $\nabla$ on a Riemannian manifold $M$, for two vector fields on $M$, $R(X,Y)=[\nabla_X, \nabla_Y]-\nabla_{[X,Y]}$. And in the setting of this theorem, the connection $\nabla_XY$is the projection of the Euclidean directional derivative of Y in the direction of X onto the tangent space of $M$.
Is there someone who will explain more about this line? I don't know what the idea/intention that the author was writing this line and why it is true.


Theorem 6.6, p. 45.

@KurtG. You mean, as Riemannian connection is determined uniquely by the metrics, so is the curvature tensor?

Quite so. The curvature tensor is uniquely determined by that connection. You wrote it in formulas.

Maybe, you know
$$
\langle Z,\nabla_Y X \rangle = \frac{1}{2}\left[
X\langle Y,Z\rangle
+Y\langle Z,X\rangle
-Z\langle X,Y\rangle
-\langle [X,Z], Y\rangle
-\langle [Y,Z], X\rangle
-\langle [X,Y], Z\rangle
\right]
\tag{1}
$$
If so, when we have Riemannian metric, then we have a unique Riemannian connection, since the RHS of (1) only depend on metric and bracket.
